# background-image not working on any browser

Tags: css, background-image

I am working on putting background images on my header and footer. When I click on design tab on VS it seems to be working but when I execute the web application, the background images won't show.

**My stylesheet**

```
#Header {
    height: 150px;
    width:1020px;
    background-color:gray;
    background-image:url('images\bg-image.png');
    background-position-x:right;
    font-size:30px;
    font-family:Arial;
}

#Footer {
    background-color:gray;
    background-image:url("e:\...\images\footer-image.png");
    width:1020px;
    height:80px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
```

As you will noticed, I've tried changing the path of the images but it's still giving me the same results.

**My VS image directory**

[image: My VS image directory]

**Result when executed (I've tried on IE, Chrome, FF)**

[image: Result]

I hope someone will help me on this. Thank you!

Comment: Those image paths are not right at all. It looks like you're mashing the absolute path with the relative path. Just use relative path only and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost certainly a path issue. Try using the full path from the web root:

```
/* Assuming the images directory is in the web root.*/
background-image:url('/images/bg-image.png');
```

Comment: Where are your images located relative your web root?

Comment: Yer, it is located inside the web root. I tried using your suggestion, when I type '/', I followed the intellisense and it worked! Maybe I was typing the wrong thing before. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `url("e:\...\images\footer-image.png")`.

Instead, you can try `file`  scheme:

```
url("file:///e:/.../images/footer-image.png")
```

However, you can only use it if the webpage is accessed using `file` scheme too. In your screenshot you are using `http`, so it won't work because of security reasons.

Then, the best option can be relative urls, that will work both with `http` and `file`:

```
url('images/bg-image.png');
```

Note the use of the slash `/` instead of the backward one `\`.

Answer (score 2):

Pathname problem. enter code herelike so:

```
#Header {
height: 150px;
width:1020px;
background-color:gray;
background-image:url('images/bg-image.png');
background-position-x:right;
font-size:30px;
font-family:Arial;
}

#Footer {
background-color:gray;
background-image:url("e:/.../images/footer-image.png");
width:1020px;
height:80px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:13px;
margin-top:5px;
}
```